# Ejecutar php en segundo plano

Tags: php, sql-server, windows

-- Espero mi explicación sea clara -- Tengo un script en PHP que tarda bastante tiempo en ejecutarse por lo que decidí ejecutarlo en un segundo plano, lo que pasa es que aun en el fichero que ejecuto el segundo script espera a que finalice esta ejecución para responder. Existe alguna forma de hacer que esto no suceda?.

Fichero 1 en este ejecuto el 2 script.

```
$param1 = escapeshellcmd($idProduct);
        $param2 = escapeshellcmd($_POST["portales"]);
        $param3 = escapeshellcmd($_SESSION["username"]);
        exec("php -f C:\wamp64\www\ruta-del-fichero\\test.php $param1 $param2 $param3 > salida.txt");
```

Fichero 2 es el que se ejecuta desde el fichero 1.

```
<?php
include "CreateProductPortals.php";
require "conex.php";
$db = new SqlConexionCreations();
$portales = explode(",", $_SERVER['argv'][2]);
$usuario = $_SERVER['argv'][3];
$result = new CreateProductPortals($portales, $db, $_SERVER['argv'][1], $usuario);
$resultado = (is_array($result) || is_object($result)) ? json_encode($result):$result;
$query = "INSERT INTO [logs_creaciones] (usuario, resultado) VALUES ('{$usuario}', '{$resultado}')";
die(var_dump($db->query($query)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas iniciar un proceso asíncrono con "popen()"
http://php.net/manual/es/function.popen.php

```
$command = 'ruta_del_script.php arg1 arg2... argn';
pclose(popen('start /b php.exe '.$command, 'r'));
```

[ Importante ] `php.ini` debe estar: `register_argc_argv = On` y el directorio del ejecutable de php, "php.exe" debe estar en `path` de las variables de entorno.

Comment: Muchas Gracias aeportugal. Esto me ha ayudado a solucionar mi inconveniente